# NFS4 does group membership have to be manually synchronised between hosts?

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I have NFS4 correctly mapping user and group IDs (using idmapd).

Does group membership have to be synchronised across hosts manually or is it handled by idmapd or NFS itself?

Example:

```
# server users
alice:1000
bob:1001

# server groups
staff:7777:alice,bob

# client users
alice:2000
bob:2001
```

Is it sufficient to declare the `staff` group on the client like this:

```
# client groups
staff:7777:
```

Or do I have to keep the group membership up to date across the hosts myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct membership on the server side is sufficient to access the files and directories. Nevertheless, NFS client can make assumptions based on the local credentials and give a false DENY. IOW, it's not required to keep groups on client and server in sync, but it helps to prevent bad surprises.